# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Invalid bean definition

Tags: java, spring, exception

I get the BeanDefinitionStoreException when I try to run the server.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition   with name 'DefaultProductSpecificationHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'xsdGenerator.DefaultProductSpecificationHandler.supportedTypes.7' in string value [${xsdGenerator.DefaultProductSpecificationHandler.supportedTypes.7}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you read the error message carefully, you'll see exactly which part of the config is failing: "Could not resolve placeholder 'xsdGenerator.DefaultProductSpecificationHandler.supportedTypes.7'"...

It looks like this placeholder was not defined.